# Dataframe - Datetime, get cumulated sum of previous day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
datetime: HH:MM:SS (not continuous, there are some missing days)
date: ['datetime'].dt.date
X = various values
X_daily_cum = df.groupby(['date']).X.cumsum()
So Xcum is the cumulated sum of X but grouped per day, it's reset every day.
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [['2021-01-01 10:10', 3],
                    ['2021-01-03 13:33', 7],
                    ['2021-01-03 14:44', 6],
                    ['2021-01-07 17:17', 2],
                    ['2021-01-07 07:07', 4],
                    ['2021-01-07 01:07', 9],
                    ['2021-01-09 09:09', 3]],
                    columns=['datetime', 'X'])


df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %M:%S')
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['X_daily_cum'] = df.groupby(['date']).X.cumsum()

print(df)
```

Now I would like a new column that takes for value the cumulated sum of previous available day, like that:

```
             datetime  X        date  X_daily_cum last_day_cum_value
0 2021-01-01 00:10:10  3  2021-01-01            3          NaN
1 2021-01-03 00:13:33  7  2021-01-03            7          3
2 2021-01-03 00:14:44  6  2021-01-03           13          3
3 2021-01-07 00:17:17  2  2021-01-07            2          13
4 2021-01-07 00:07:07  4  2021-01-07            6          13
5 2021-01-07 00:01:07  9  2021-01-07           15          13
6 2021-01-09 00:09:09  3  2021-01-09            3          15
```

Is there a clean way to do it with pandas with an apply ?

I have managed to do it in a disgusting way by copying the df, removing datetime granularity, selecting last record of each date, joining this new df with the previous one. It's disgusting, I would like a more elegant solution.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for set missing values to all values without last per dates, then shifting values and forward filling missing values:

```
df['last_day_cum_value'] = (df['X_daily_cum'].mask(df['date'].duplicated(keep='last'))
                                             .shift()
                                             .ffill())
print (df)
             datetime  X        date  X_daily_cum  last_day_cum_value
0 2021-01-01 00:10:10  3  2021-01-01            3                 NaN
1 2021-01-03 00:13:33  7  2021-01-03            7                 3.0
2 2021-01-03 00:14:44  6  2021-01-03           13                 3.0
3 2021-01-07 00:17:17  2  2021-01-07            2                13.0
4 2021-01-07 00:07:07  4  2021-01-07            6                13.0
5 2021-01-07 00:01:07  9  2021-01-07           15                13.0
6 2021-01-09 00:09:09  3  2021-01-09            3                15.0
```

Old solution:

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with Series created by `date` and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) for previous dates, then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates('date', keep='last').set_index('date')['X_daily_cum'].shift()
print (s)
date
2021-01-01     NaN
2021-01-03     3.0
2021-01-07    13.0
2021-01-09    15.0
Name: X_daily_cum, dtype: float64

df['last_day_cum_value'] = df['date'].map(s)
print (df)
             datetime  X        date  X_daily_cum  last_day_cum_value
0 2021-01-01 00:10:10  3  2021-01-01            3                 NaN
1 2021-01-03 00:13:33  7  2021-01-03            7                 3.0
2 2021-01-03 00:14:44  6  2021-01-03           13                 3.0
3 2021-01-07 00:17:17  2  2021-01-07            2                13.0
4 2021-01-07 00:07:07  4  2021-01-07            6                13.0
5 2021-01-07 00:01:07  9  2021-01-07           15                13.0
6 2021-01-09 00:09:09  3  2021-01-09            3                15.0
```